# Тест на переход на требуемое активити

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development, android-testing

Всех приветствую. Требуется помощь в написании теста, после нажатия на кнопку переход на нужное активити.

Тест

```
  @Test
public void checkingPasswordEditTextWithNumberOfSymbols() {
    //Put name inside edit field
    onView(withId(R.id.et_password)).perform(typeText("12356!"));

    //Clicking on the button
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_save_user)).perform(click());

    //Starting intent testing
    Intents.init();

    intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));

    Intents.release();
}
```

Rule

```
  @Rule
public ActivityTestRule<UserActivity> mUserActivity = new ActivityTestRule<>(UserActivity.class);
```

Ошибка

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method trackUsage(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/support/test/internal/runner/tracker/UsageTracker; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.test.internal.runner.tracker.UsageTracker' appears in /data/app/com.example.boris.spectrum.test-0zo0b7HzT7jz05jGpPD6nw==/base.apk)
    at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.<clinit>(Intents.java:93)
    at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.init(Intents.java:128)
    at com.example.boris.spectrum.ExampleUnitTest.checkingPasswordEditTextWithNumberOfSymbols(ExampleUnitTest.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C помощью UiAutomator

```
UiDevice mDevice = 
UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
UiObject nextBtn = mDevice.findObject(new 
UiSelector().resourceId("your.app.package:id/your_btn_id"));
if(nextBtn.waitForExists(3000)){
nextBtn.click()
}
```

узнать id можно с помощью Android Studio-> Tools-> Layout Inspector,
подоробнее [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator)